# Create a counter that persists between runs of a windows CMD file?

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables, windows-server-2008-r2

In a Windows Server 2008r2 environment, I have CMD files (not Powershell) that run as scheduled tasks. I'm looking for a way to implement the logic:
"if this error condition has occurred in all of the past ten runs of this command, do something (like send a text message)"

So I'd like to implement a persistent counter to store the error count from prior runs of the CMD.

I searched on setting values into the system environment, ([SETX](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)) but it seems to take effect later and has other downsides.
Alternatively, a persistent counter could be implemented by writing files 1.txt, 2.txt, etc, but that seems complex and ugly.

Either of these approaches could probably work with sufficient time and effort, but I thought I'd check here in case anyone has done something like this before.  Does anyone have a more elegant way of implementing a counter with a state that persists between separate runs of a windows CMD file?

Usually by the time I finish writing a question, I see the answer is already showing in Similar Questions, but in this case I don't, so I'll go ahead and post.

Comment: Let us assume the environment variable which is used as counter has the name `Counter`. Then you can use `>"%APPDATA%\%~n0.ini" echo Counter=%Counter%` in the batch file to save the current value of the environment variable into a text file with name of batch file and file extension `.ini` in application data directory before exiting batch file and use `if exist "%APPDATA%\%~n0.ini" (for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%APPDATA%\%~n0.ini") do set "%%I") else set "Counter=0"` to reload variable with last value from the INI file and define variable `Counter` with loaded value at top of bat file.

Comment: setting `%_counter%` and then trying to work with `%counter%` isn't very helpful.

Comment: @Stephan, you're right - I misread the ss64 text on SET /A that says "SET /A allows you to omit the %'s so _myvar instead of %_myvar%"   as "SET /A allows you to omit the %'s so _myvar instead of %myvar%"    IE I thought the _ was instead of the %'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mofi provided the solution with some advanced techniques in his comment. It was unclear to me due to comment formatting limitations, so I created a test script.
@Stephan noticed I misread the substitution of _ for %%.
Further debugging showed that the arithmetic comparison form of IF does not work with ( ), so re-structured to use goto. Here is a working script:

```
rem read in existing cntr
if exist "%APPDATA%\%~n0.ini"    (
  for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%APPDATA%\%~n0.ini") do set "%%I"
) else (
  set "cntr=0"
)
                         
rem cntr is %cntr%                        
set /a "cntr+=1"
rem cntr is %cntr%                        

if  %cntr% LEQ 10  goto under
    echo Count exceeded 10
    set cntr=0
:under
rem cntr is %cntr%   
rem write back out to cntr file
>"%APPDATA%\%~n0.ini" echo cntr=%cntr%
```

This results in this output:

```
c:\>test-pers-counter.cmd
c:\>rem read in existing cntr
c:\>if exist "C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\test-pers-counter.ini" (for /F "usebackq delims=" %I in ("C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\test-pers-counter.ini") do set "%I" )  else (set "cntr=0" )
c:\>rem cntr is 0
c:\>set /A "cntr+=1"
c:\>rem cntr is 1
c:\>if 1 LEQ 10 goto under
c:\>rem cntr is 1
c:\>rem write back out to cntr file
c:\>echo cntr=1 1>"C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\test-pers-counter.ini"

---------SNIP additional runs for count 1 through 9------------------

c:\>test-pers-counter.cmd
c:\>rem read in existing cntr
c:\>if exist "C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\test-pers-counter.ini" (for /F "usebackq delims=" %I in ("C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\test-pers-counter.ini") do set "%I" )  else (set "cntr=0" )
c:\>set "cntr=10"
c:\>rem cntr is 10
c:\>set /a "cntr+=1"
c:\>rem cntr is 11
c:\>if 11 LEQ 10 goto under
c:\>echo Count exceeded 10
Count exceeded 10
c:\>set cntr=0
c:\>rem cntr is 0
c:\>rem write back out to cntr file
c:\>echo cntr=0 1>"C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\test-pers-counter.ini"
c:\>
```